# How do I bond eth0 to failover to wlan0 after WAN connection loss?

Tags: debian, wifi, failover, network-monitoring, bonding

I would like to have my monitoring box (Zenoss) notify me when the network upstream of me goes down without an actual link loss.

I have had some issues with our CoLo's switches going down, but I don't know until our users notify us.

I would like to have a LTE wifi hotspot to fail over to so I can send notifications from Zenoss about the outage / any other internal issues without being completely dependant on the DC's connection, but would like to avoid using the LTE data whenever possible.

I am using Debian 7

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to configure the bond as follows:

- `miimon=100` because you need a link monitoring mode. You could also use `arp_interval=1000` and `arp_ip_target=gate.way.ip` if you wished.
- `mode=1` or `mode=active-backup` so that only one connection is used at a time.
- `primary=eth0` so the Ethernet interface is used whenever it's available.
- `fail_over_mac=active` so that the bond's MAC is changed to the active slave's MAC on failover. You need to do this because almost all wireless devices don't pass traffic with a MAC address which isn't their own.

These options are explained further in the upstream Linux kernel [bonding.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/bonding.txt)

---

I don't know much about Debian and the [Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/Bonding) page is not very clear. I'm marking this as *Community Wiki* so someone else can improve it with an exact `/etc/network/interfaces` file which will work for you.

Comment: This led me down the exact path I was looking for!
Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Cool :) If you wish, you could post the bonding part of your `/etc/network/interfaces` file to help others who have the same question.